# GADBannerView in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell` with a `GADBannerView` inside. I setup the cell via `.xib` but when I try to load the request I get an errore `no adv to show`. The same code used at the bottom of `UIViewController` works fine.
But when I put the same view inside `UITableViewCell` doesn't work anymore.

[image]

Here `cell.m`:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)startBannerRequestWithRootViewController:(id)viewController
{
    self.bannerView.adUnitID = ADV_HOME_BANNER_ID;
    self.bannerView.delegate = self;
    self.bannerView.rootViewController = viewController;
    [self.bannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}
```

And here how I use it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
TreeTableViewCell_ADV * cell = (TreeTableViewCell_ADV *)[self dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kADVCellIdentifier];

TreeNode * aNode = [self nodeAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[cell startBannerRequestWithRootViewController:aNode.internalObject];

return cell;
```

Where

```
aNode.internalObject
```

contains a view controller to use as root of the banner.

Ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I will add advertising through code. Everything works fine

For example. I hope to help

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) GADBannerView *bannerView;


- (void)startBannerRequestWithRootViewController:(id)viewController {
    if ([self bannerView]) {
        return;
    } else {
        _bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
        [_bannerView setAdUnitID:@"replace"];
        _bannerView.rootViewController = viewController;
        [_bannerView setDelegate:self];
        [_bannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
        [[self contentView] addSubview:_bannerView];
    }
}
```